# constructor and typecasting

Tags: java, casting

> i took it from a website about misunderstanding of implicit casting.i ran this code on compiler.it shows error as "return type for method is missing" in the lines 7,11,15,19 across constructors(but constructors should not have any return type) moreover the errors are like"TypeTest cannot be resolved to a type" on line 24.what is the wrong here?
>   how to correct this?

[http://mrbool.com/java-data-type-conversion/29257]

( go to common misunderstandings for the code )

```
public class TypeText {

TypeTest(double a, double b, short c) {
    System.out.println("1 (dbldbl short)");
}

TypeTest(float a, byte b, long c) {
    System.out.println("2 (float byte long)");
}


TypeTest(long a, long b, long c) {
    System.out.println("3 (long long long)");
}

TypeTest(float a, long b, short c) {
    System.out.println("4 (float long short)");
}

TypeTest(double a, double b, double c) {
    System.out.println("5 (dbldbldbl)");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TypeTest t = new TypeTest();
    t.TypeTest(3.4, 3L, 3);
}
```

Comment: what will be the output for this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo :

change

```
public class TypeText
```

to

```
public class TypeTest
```

In addition :

```
TypeTest t = new TypeTest(); // this is invalid since you have no parameterless
                             // constructor
t.TypeTest(3.4, 3L, 3); // this is invalid since you have no TypeTest method in
                        // your class
```

Perhaps you meant to try :

```
TypeTest t = new TypeTest(3.4, 3L, 3);
```

Comment: i changed and checked on compiler and posted here

Comment: again i got errors on 24,25 as the constructor TypeTest is undefined.and  the method TypeTest(double,long,int) is undefined for the type TypeTest

Comment: @t72belt90 What errors are you getting now? Did you fix the class name?

Comment: i fixed the class name and recompiled it and got error on line 24 and 25